# Java Unit Test on method with input

Tags: java, unit-testing

When I use the method "execute(p)" there is a list when I must chose an item :

```
@Override
public void execute(Player p) {
    // listchoser with items available
    ListChoser lc = new ListChoser();
    Object itemChosen;
    itemChosen = lc.chose("Which item?", p.getCurrentRoom().getItems());
    System.out.println("You chose " + itemChosen.toString());
    // put item effect on player
    ((Item) itemChosen).effect(p);
    // remove item from current room
    p.getCurrentRoom().removeItem(itemChosen);
}
```

I must do some Unit Tests on it so here how I proceed :

```
Player c;
Action useAction;

@Before
public void initiliaze() {
    c = new Player("Test", 100, 100,100);
    c.setCurrentRoom(new Room("Debug Room", false));
    useAction = new UseAction();
}

@Test
public void testUseAction(){
    List<? super Item> l = c.getCurrentRoom().getItems();
    int nbItems = l.size();
    useAction.execute(c);
    assertEquals(nbItems-1, c.getCurrentRoom().getItems().size());
}
```

I have some trouble to deal with such tests when I launch them : I'm asked for an input when I should only use a default one (like the 0 one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend spliting your execute() method into 2 separate methods so first of them only takes an input, processes it and passes a result of an operation to the second one that contains all the rest of logic.

That makes your code consistient with [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)'s Single responsibility principle and also enables testing that part of code that is responsible for the logic, without taking any input from user(you can just pass some prepared object)

Comment: I'm going to try this approach

Answer (score 1):

Interactive code and unit testing do not match well. That is why a test-first approach helps to write clean and testable code. If writing test code afterwards you are forced to spend time on rewriting the program code for testability.

A quick and dirty solution is to add another method and call it from the existing one like this:

```
@Override
public void execute(Player p) {
    execute(Player p, new ListChoser());
}

public void execute(Player p, ListChoser lc) {
    Object itemChosen;
    if (lc != null) {
        itemChosen = lc.chose("Which item?", p.getCurrentRoom().getItems());
        System.out.println("You chose " + itemChosen.toString());
    }
    else { //add exception handling if list is empty
        itemChosen = p.getCurrentRoom().getItems()[0];
    }
    // put item effect on player
    ((Item) itemChosen).effect(p);
    // remove item from current room
    p.getCurrentRoom().removeItem(itemChosen);
}
```

And use this new method for your test, for example like this:

```
@Test
public void testUseAction(){
    List<? super Item> l = c.getCurrentRoom().getItems();
    int nbItems = l.size();
    useAction.execute(c, null); //use null for default behaviour
    assertEquals(nbItems-1, c.getCurrentRoom().getItems().size());
}
```

That way you can at least test the non-interactive part of your code.

A better solution would be a complete redesign of `ListChoser` as an interface and implement an  `InteractiveListChoser` and a `TestListChoser`. Separating type (=interface) from implementation (=class) is a design principle that works well for unit-testing.

Comment: I thought about it and when I tried to write my UnitTest I was like "hell this is not the SOLID principle". Now I feel trapped and I don't want to use a dirty solution. I'm going to look for some other thing even If I have to rewrite code